# for loop only showing last object from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

Hi Stack Overflow community. I'm a beginner in .js and jQuery and I am sort of racking my brain here.

I've created an array of objects

```
var questions = [  

{
    question: "What is Capital of Canada",
    choices:["Ottawa","Toronto","Montreal","Vancouver"],
},

{
    question: "What is the capital of France",
    choices:["Paris","Lille","Bordeaux","Lyon"],
},
{
    question: "What is the capital of Brazil",
    choices:["Curitiba","Rio de Janeiro","Sao Paolo","Brasilia"],
},
```

I've created the 'click' handler for my button

```
$("#nextQ").bind('click', displayQuestion);
```

and lastly, I've created my function with the for loop that should cycle though my questions

```
function displayQuestion() {

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

        $("#quiz").html("<h2>" + questions[i].question +"</h2>" 
            + "<ol id=question type=A> <li id=choice1>" 
            + questions[i].choices[0] + "</li>" 
            + "<li id=choice2>" + questions[i].choices[1] 
            + "</li>" + "<li id=choice3>"
            + questions[i].choices[2] + "</li>" 
            + "<li id=choice4>" 
            + questions[i].choices[3] + "</li> </ol>");


    };
```

The problem I'm having is that every time I click the "#nextQ" button in my HTML, it always displays the last item in my array, no matter how many items I have in it. It will go straight from questions[0].question to questions[2].question and .choices, or questions[9].question and .choices if I have 10 questions for example.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Nothing in the search bar made much sense to me.

Comment: Are you trying to display all the questions at the same time? If you're only trying to retrieve one at a time, you shouldn't be using a loop.

Comment: Each loop overwrites the previous, you need to append it. Create a string, build your response and assigns the whole lot outside of the loop (assuming your trying to create a block of all questions)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to display *one* question at a time, you have no reason to use a loop of any sort. Something like this may be more in line with what you're trying to achieve:

```
var i = 0;
function displayQuestion() {

    $("#quiz").html("<h2>" + questions[i].question +"</h2>" 
        + "<ol id=question type=A> <li id=choice1>" 
        + questions[i].choices[0] + "</li>" 
        + "<li id=choice2>" + questions[i].choices[1] 
        + "</li>" + "<li id=choice3>"
        + questions[i].choices[2] + "</li>" 
        + "<li id=choice4>" 
        + questions[i].choices[3] + "</li> </ol>");

    i++;
});
```

If you are trying to display *all* questions at the same time, then your issue is that for each iteration of your loop, you're setting the `html` of `#quiz` rather than adding to it. This will display all questions on the screen:

```
function displayQuestion() {

    var $q = $("#quiz");

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        $q.append("<h2>" + questions[i].question +"</h2>" 
            + "<ol id=question type=A> <li id=choice1>" 
            + questions[i].choices[0] + "</li>" 
            + "<li id=choice2>" + questions[i].choices[1] 
            + "</li>" + "<li id=choice3>"
            + questions[i].choices[2] + "</li>" 
            + "<li id=choice4>" 
            + questions[i].choices[3] + "</li> </ol>");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to pop the question from the array and display it.

```
function displayQuestion() {
    var nextQuestion= questions.pop();

    $("#quiz").html("<h2>" + nextQuestion.question +"</h2>" 
        + "<ol id=question type=A> <li id=choice1>" 
        + nextQuestion.choices[0] + "</li>" 
        + "<li id=choice2>" + nextQuestion.choices[1] 
        + "</li>" + "<li id=choice3>"
        + nextQuestion.choices[2] + "</li>" 
        + "<li id=choice4>" 
        + nextQuestion.choices[3] + "</li> </ol>");


};
```

or if you want to keep the questions in the array and increment the question index to get the next question:

```
var i = 0;
function displayQuestion() {
    ++i;

    $("#quiz").html("<h2>" + questions[i].question +"</h2>" 
        + "<ol id=question type=A> <li id=choice1>" 
        + questions[i].choices[0] + "</li>" 
        + "<li id=choice2>" + questions[i].choices[1] 
        + "</li>" + "<li id=choice3>"
        + questions[i].choices[2] + "</li>" 
        + "<li id=choice4>" 
        + questions[i].choices[3] + "</li> </ol>");


};
```

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments said, in the loop, you overwrite the HTML of your display division with one question after another.  So on every click of the button you quickly rewrite that section with each question.

I'm assuming, though, that your requirements are just to show one question at a time.  That means you need to keep track of the current question somewhere.  Here's a naive version:

```
var current = -1;

function displayQuestion() {
    current += 1;
    var i = current % questions.length;

    $("#quiz").html("<h2>" + questions[i].question +"</h2>" 
        + "<ol id=question type=A> <li id=choice1>" 
        + questions[i].choices[0] + "</li>" 
        + "<li id=choice2>" + questions[i].choices[1] 
        + "</li>" + "<li id=choice3>"
        + questions[i].choices[2] + "</li>" 
        + "<li id=choice4>" 
        + questions[i].choices[3] + "</li> </ol>");
}
```

This works as you can see in **[a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/pqvsojcq/)**.

But I call it naive because it introduces a global state variable, which is almost never a good idea.  Rather, this version encapsulates that state in the closure of your function:

```
var displayQuestion = (function() {
    var current = -1;
    return function displayQuestion() {
        current += 1;
        var i = current % questions.length;

        $("#quiz").html("<h2>" + questions[i].question +"</h2>" 
            + "<ol id=question type=A> <li id=choice1>" 
            + questions[i].choices[0] + "</li>" 
            + "<li id=choice2>" + questions[i].choices[1] 
            + "</li>" + "<li id=choice3>"
            + questions[i].choices[2] + "</li>" 
            + "<li id=choice4>" 
            + questions[i].choices[3] + "</li> </ol>");
    };
}());
```

This one is in **[another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/wxez9v8d/)**.

Both of these make the simplifying assumption that you will loop around to the beginning of the list when you fall off the end.  That many not be justified, and you may need to do something slightly more complex.

Also note that there is no real reason for keeping the `current` value separate from your `i` variable.  I was just feeling lazy.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are replacing every time the question by using $("#quiz").html 
You should use append function of jquery to see all the questions